# How to check iframe nested at tampermonkey?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, tampermonkey

I wrote code to run on iframes on a site. My problem is that this code works in iframes in iframe.My wish is that the code will only run on the iframe inside the top window.

Comment: if (parent === top) { ........ }

Comment: @wOxxOm Is it possible to do this check with tampermonkey? After all, it doesn't prevent the code from being injected.